# CLang prog segmentation fault in ((CXXMethodDecl*)(VarDecl->getParentFunctionOrMethod()))

Tags: c++, clang

I am compiling my program which uses `Clang 3.5` on `Ubuntu 13.04 x86` machine. I wanted to get all the variables declared in a cpp project. Here is what I wrote:-

```
// Declares clang::SyntaxOnlyAction.
#include "clang/Frontend/FrontendActions.h"
#include "clang/Tooling/CommonOptionsParser.h"
#include "clang/Tooling/Tooling.h"
#include "clang/ASTMatchers/ASTMatchers.h"
#include "clang/ASTMatchers/ASTMatchFinder.h"
// Declares llvm::cl::extrahelp.
#include "llvm/Support/CommandLine.h"
#include "clang/AST/DeclCXX.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace clang::tooling;
using namespace llvm;
using namespace clang::ast_matchers;
using namespace clang;
using namespace std;

static cl::extrahelp CommonHelp(CommonOptionsParser::HelpMessage);

static cl::extrahelp MoreHelp("\nMore help text...");

static cl::OptionCategory MyToolCategory("My Tool Category");

internal::Matcher<Decl> fields = fieldDecl().bind("field");
internal::Matcher<Decl> params = parmVarDecl().bind("param");
internal::Matcher<Decl> vars = varDecl().bind("var");

class VarDeclPrinter : public MatchFinder::MatchCallback {
  public:
  int counter;

  virtual void run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult &Result) {
    const Decl* dec;

    if(const FieldDecl* field = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<FieldDecl>("field"))
      llvm::outs() << "Member Variable: " << field->getName() << "\t\t" 
                   << field->getParent()->getQualifiedNameAsString() << "\n";

    if(const ParmVarDecl* param = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<ParmVarDecl>("param"))
      llvm::outs() << "Argument Variable: " << param->getName() << "\t\t"
                   << ((CXXMethodDecl*)(param->getParentFunctionOrMethod()))->getQualifiedNameAsString() << "\n";

    if(const VarDecl* var = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<VarDecl>("var"))
      llvm::outs() << "Local Variable: " << var->getName() << "\t\t"
                   << ((CXXMethodDecl*)(var->getParentFunctionOrMethod()))->getQualifiedNameAsString() << "\n";

    counter++;
    //llvm::outs() << "Variable count: " << counter << "\n";
    //ASTContext* Context = Result.Context;
  }
};

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
  CommonOptionsParser OptionsParser(argc, argv, MyToolCategory);
  ClangTool Tool(OptionsParser.getCompilations(),
                 OptionsParser.getSourcePathList());

  VarDeclPrinter VarDeclCallback;
  MatchFinder Finder;

  Finder.addMatcher(fields, &VarDeclCallback);
  Finder.addMatcher(params, &VarDeclCallback);
  Finder.addMatcher(vars, &VarDeclCallback);
  return Tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory(&Finder));
}
```

When I try running this program, I get **segmentation fault** (possibly when I am casting `var->getParentFunctionOrMethod()` to `CXXMethodDecl*`). I wanted the method name where this variable is declared if it is a local variable. Can anybody tell me what may be the reasons for the error? Or what could be a better way to get method name of the variable?

Comment: This is often a good time in your life to learn how to use debugging tools. I recommend GDB for general debugging, and the Valgrind suite for the more onerous memory issues.

Comment: GDB is a great tool. Its just not working in my case. I added `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` to the cmake of llvm. After taking a lot of compilation time (than before when executing make), now its giving me `libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a: file format not recognized; treating as linker script`. Thanks for comment anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution. It was because I was trying to fetch **method name** even if `var` is not inside method. Here is the solution:-

```
if(const VarDecl* var = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<VarDecl>("var")) {
  llvm::outs() << "Local Variable: " << var->getName() << "\t\t";
  if(var->isFunctionOrMethodVarDecl())
    llvm::outs() << ((CXXMethodDecl*)(var->getParentFunctionOrMethod()))->getQualifiedNameAsString();
  llvm::outs() << "\n";
}
```